# Highlight Duplicates Not Next To Each Other Using Conditional Formatting

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

We have a list of parts in Excel in a certain order. For reasons I won't get into, we need to highlight when there are duplicates that aren't next to each other. Currently, I'm using this formula in a conditional format to do the job.

`=AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$82,$A2)>1,$A1<>$A2,$A2<>$A3)`

This mostly works well except in cases where there are pairs of duplicates like in the example below, we would want FO-1694 to be highlighted, because they aren't all next to each other. But we would not want NIS0257 to be highlighted because they are.

Currently
[image: Current]

Ideally, this is what we want to see...

Expected
[image: Expected]

Any ideas on this could be achieved using conditional formatting?

<sub>Note: I have directly posted this from a past post on the SuperUser Forum ([Link](https://superuser.com/questions/826257/highlight-duplicates-not-next-to-each-other-using-conditional-formatting)) as I am in need of this EXACT conditional formatting for the EXACT same circumstances. I do not take credit for the construction of this post, but only hope to obtain an answer for a question that previously went unanswered.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=NOT(AND(A2=OFFSET(A2,COUNTIF($A2:$A$82,A2)-1,0),A2=OFFSET(A2,-(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)-1),0)))
```

[image]

If changing the range then make sure to pay attention to what is marked as absolute and relative.

Comment: You sir, are an absolute saint! I've been racking my brain for a day an a half trying to figure out a way to accomplish this. Shamefully enough, I disregarded using <code>Offset</code> in this situation and for some reason my brain kept trying ideas with <code>Find</code> and <code>Index</code>. Regardless, thank you for passing on this knowledge and helping me solve my problem!

Comment: @CaffeineCoder Glad I could help.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I shared your solution over on the original user's post ([link](http://superuser.com/a/1033591/551593))as well (citing you as the author of the solution and deserving of all the credit of course)

Comment: @CaffeineCoder one off these days I need to have a login over there also.  I do not mind.