# Highlight duplicates not next to each other using conditional formatting (Larger Dataset)

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

> We have a list of product numbers in Excel in a certain order. For reasons I won't get into, we need to highlight when there are duplicates that aren't next to each other.Currently, I'm using this formula in a conditional format to do the job.
>
> `=AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$82,$A2)>1,$A1<>$A2,$A2<>$A3)`
>
> This mostly works well except in cases where there are pairs of duplicates like in the example below, we would want FO-1694 to be highlighted, because they aren't all next to each other. But we would not want NIS0257 to be highlighted because they are.
>
> Currently
>
> [image: past 1]
>
> Ideally, this is what we want to see...
>
> Expected
>
> [image: past 2]

I originally asked this same question January 30th ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098014/highlight-duplicates-not-next-to-each-other-using-conditional-formatting)) and I received what seemed to be a working [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35098161/2962937) with the conditional formatting formula

```
=NOT(AND(A2=OFFSET(A2,COUNTIF($A2:$A$82,A2)-1,0),A2=OFFSET(A2,-(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)-1),0)))
```

While this original answer appears to work for a small group of data ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/076bo.png)), it does not function as needed on much larger datasets like the ones I'll be dealing with (images below are of the issues with the larger dataset). I've adjusted the formula as necessary to accommodate the larger range, so the conditional formatting formula you see in the larger dataset pictures & file is

```
=NOT(AND(A2=OFFSET(A2,COUNTIF($A2:$A$5422,A2)-1,0),A2=OFFSET(A2,-(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)-1),0)))
```

Cells with the arrow pointing at them should be highlighted

[image: problem screenshots]
[image: problem screenshots]

[image: problem screenshots]
[image: problem screenshots]

For the last picture, even though it's the end of the range the cells should still be highlighted since they're blank and I need all blank cells in the range to be highlighted too.

The full file with the larger dataset can be downloaded from my dropbox account using this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4sgmxatkddhw47/StackOverflowExampleFile.xlsx?dl=0).

Comment: I think you'll need to use an array to get the rows where it appears, like if(a1:a10=a1,row(a1:a10)) then if the next smallest and the next largest instances are not the current row +/-1 then format, so if the array gets 2,3,5,7 as the rows, then if we are on row 5, the +/- in the array would be rows 3 and 5, i'll continue to play....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have thought of those problems:

```
=NOT(AND(IFERROR(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,0,0,-COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A2)),A2),0)=IFERROR(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A2),0),IFERROR(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A3,0,0,COUNTIF($A3:$A$5422,A2)),A2),0)=IFERROR(COUNTIF($A3:$A$5422,A2),0),A2<>""))
```

Should do it.

Comment: Have you ever been told "I love you" by a tall lanky nerd? Well, I love you. Thanks again for all of your help. I just played around with the new formula and it's looking like all the situations check out!

Comment: there is only one tiny problem left with the revised code and that is if the last cell of the range is populated and is not a duplicate it still highlights that value. See photo [here](http://i.imgur.com/EUfDJMD.jpg)

Comment: @CaffeineCoder As to your first enlarge the `$A$5422` to always be one row larger than your data set so in this case `$A$5423`.  As to the second I am not getting that.  I erased the value in A18, and Am still getting the formula to return true for A17.

Comment: A simple solution, thanks! As for the second problem, I realized after posting it that it was null and was due to a completely unrelated matter (overlapping conditional formatting formula, which has been removed), so I removed that comment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would work for you

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,A2)>2,1,IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,A2)=2,A1<>A2,A3<>A2),1,0))
```

I've tested it on a test bit of data, and seems to work.  You need to check for the 1st row, as you cant check the previous cell, so the A1<>A2 part..

1 being true condition on my test so would need tweaking for conditional formatting.
Enjoy.